# Android listview not updated

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, baseadapter

I working viewpager.i have some pages.i  also have listview witch adaptered some images and texts.
i wrote function witch has int position witch means each position i try to adapter different values.
i use this function in my viewpager's setOnPageChangeListener method,but i can not updated my listview

this is a my adapter source code

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context activity;
private List<CopyOfServerItems> items;
private CopyOfServerItems objBean;
private int row;

public ImageLoader imageLoader;


public MyAdapter(Context act, int resource, List<CopyOfServerItems> arrayList
        ) {
    super();
    this.activity = act;
    this.row = resource;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(act.getApplicationContext());
    this.items = arrayList;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
        return view;

    objBean = items.get(position);



    holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cat_title);
    holder.img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cat_image);



    holder.title.setText(objBean.getTitle());





    imageLoader.DisplayImage(objBean.getThumbnail(), holder.img);
    //holder.img.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);

    return view;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView  title;
    public ImageView img;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}




@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}
}
```

this is  a my java codee

```
public class CategoryViewPager extends Fragment {
public final static String TAG = CategoryViewPager.class
        .getSimpleName();
public static List<CopyOfServerItems> arrayOfList;

public static List<CopyOfServerItems> arrayOfList1;

private MyAdapter objAdapter;

public static CategoryViewPager newInstance() {
    return new CategoryViewPager();
}


private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ListView cat_listview;
private PagerTitleStrip mPagerTitleStrip;
String result;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.azercell_category_viewpager,
            container, false);
    arrayOfList = new ArrayList<CopyOfServerItems>();
    arrayOfList1 = new ArrayList<CopyOfServerItems>();
    final List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();
    final ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mPagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.pagertitle);

    LayoutInflater inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View page = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.azercell_category_pages, null);

    page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.azercell_category_pages, null);

    cat_listview = (ListView) page.findViewById(R.id.cat_listview);

    mPagerTitleStrip.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);



    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfList.size(); i++) {

        page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.azercell_category_pages, null);
        cat_listview = (ListView) page.findViewById(R.id.cat_listview);
        cat_listview.setAdapter(objAdapter);

        titles.add(arrayOfList.get(i).getTitle());




        pages.add(page);



    }
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            try {

                Log.e("position viewpager", String.valueOf(arg0));
                parseJsonFromServer(result, arg0);
                objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {


        }
    });


    PagerAdapter p_adapter = new PagerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            return arg0 == arg1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return pages.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView(pages.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return titles.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(pages.get(position));
            return pages.get(position);
        }

    };
    mViewPager.setAdapter(p_adapter);

    return rootView;
}





public String parseJsonFromServer(String server, int position)
        throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(server);
    jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray("result");

    JSONArray children = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getJSONArray(
            "children");

    for (int j = 0; j < children.length(); j++) {

        CopyOfServerItems objItem = new CopyOfServerItems();
        JSONObject data = children.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("data");

        objItem.setTitle(data.getString("title"));
        objItem.setThumbnail(data.getString("thumbnail"));
        Log.e("123123123123", data.getString("title"));

        arrayOfList1.add(objItem);
    }


    setAdapterToListview();
    return server;
}


public void setAdapterToListview() {
    objAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.azercell_category_adapter, arrayOfList1);

    objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

}
```

My parseJsonFromServer parse server by position.when position changed also must change my json.i did it.but if i  use position 0 and then position 1  my adapter can not updated.i can show all values (i mean 0 and 1 position)
how i can solved my problem?
if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: You should get a null pointer exception at this line cat_listview.setAdapter(objAdapter);

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** All of your code looks wrong I am sorry that this may not work.

Firstly it is better to return position as object id:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}
```

secondly, you shouldn't change adapter to update listview. You should update your adapter data.

add this to your adapter:

```
updateData( int resource, List<CopyOfServerItems> arrayList ){

    this.row = resource;
    this.items = arrayList;

}
```

and change setAdapterToListView with this:

```
updateListView( int resource, List<CopyOfServerItems> arrayList ){

     objAdapter.updateData( resource, arrayList );
     objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

I would want to explain it in Turkish or Azerbaijani but site rules doesn't allow me. So it is the best what I can do to help you. Hope it Works.

**EDIT:** Change your code to something like that:

```
public class CategoryViewPager extends Fragment {

public final static String TAG = CategoryViewPager.class
        .getSimpleName();
public static List<CopyOfServerItems> arrayOfList;

public static List<CopyOfServerItems> arrayOfList1;

private MyAdapter[] objAdapter;

public static CategoryViewPager newInstance() {
    return new CategoryViewPager();
}


private ViewPager mViewPager;

private ListView[] cat_listview;

private PagerTitleStrip mPagerTitleStrip;
String result;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.azercell_category_viewpager,
            container, false);
    arrayOfList = new ArrayList<CopyOfServerItems>();
    arrayOfList1 = new ArrayList<CopyOfServerItems>();
    final List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();
    final ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mPagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.pagertitle);

    mPagerTitleStrip.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    cat_listview = new ListView[  arrayOfList.size() ];
    objAdapter   = new MyAdapter[ arrayOfList.size() ];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfList.size(); i++) {

        View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.azercell_category_pages, null);
        cat_listviews[ i ] = (ListView) page.findViewById(R.id.cat_listview);

        objAdapter[ i ] = new MyAdapter( [put some paremeters here] );

        cat_listview[ i ].setAdapter(objAdapter[ i ] );

        titles.add(arrayOfList.get(i).getTitle());

        pages.add(page);    
    }

    .........


    public String parseJsonFromServer(String server, int position)

        throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(server);
    jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray("result");

    JSONArray children = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getJSONArray(
            "children");

    for (int j = 0; j < children.length(); j++) {

        CopyOfServerItems objItem = new CopyOfServerItems();
        JSONObject data = children.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("data");

        objItem.setTitle(data.getString("title"));
        objItem.setThumbnail(data.getString("thumbnail"));
        Log.e("123123123123", data.getString("title"));

        arrayOfList1.add(objItem);
    }


    updateListview( resource, obj, position );
    return server;
}


updateListView( int resource, List<CopyOfServerItems> arrayList ){

     objAdapter[ position ].updateData( resource, arrayList );
     objAdapter[ position ].notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

and the code I send before to your adapter.

Comment: i tryed it but i have exception

Comment: There are some problems in your code. You don't store all of your listviews. You store only the last one. Give me sometime to code something for you.

Comment: Can you post CopyOfServerItems class?

Comment: Well sorry that I need too many things to help you and I have my own Works to do now. There are what you should do:

1) store one adapter per page.
2) store one listview per page.
3) update them in the way I told you.

Note: I have added some code to help you but this all what I can do